# sampling with weight using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, sampling

I have an unbalanced dataframe on spark using PySpark. 
I want to resample it to make it balanced. 
I only find the sample function in PySpark

```
sample(withReplacement, fraction, seed=None)
```

but I want to sample the dataframe with weight of unitvolume
in Python, I can do it like

```
df.sample(n,Flase,weights=log(unitvolume))
```

is there any method I could do the same using PySpark?

Answer (score 3):

Spark provides tools for stratified sampling, but this work only on categorical data. You could try to bucketize it:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, log

df_log = df.withColumn("log_unitvolume", log(col("unitvolume"))
splits = ... # A list of splits

bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=splits, inputCol="log_unitvolume", outputCol="bucketed_log_unitvolume")

df_log_bucketed = bucketizer.transform(df_log)
```

Compute statistics:

```
counts = df.groupBy("bucketed_log_unitvolume")
fractions  = ...  # Define fractions from each bucket:
```

and use these for sampling:

```
df_log_bucketed.sampleBy("bucketed_log_unitvolume", fractions)
```

You can also try to rescale `log_unitvolume` to [0, 1] range and then:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand 

df_log_rescaled.where(col("log_unitvolume_rescaled") < rand())
```

Comment: Is there any similar way in spark 2.4 ?? I saw that Bucketizer is released from spark 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be better to simply ignore the .sample() function altogether. Sampling without replacement can be implemented with a uniform random number generator:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

n_samples_appx = 100
total_weight = df.agg(F.sum('weight')).collect().values
df.filter(F.rand(seed=843) < F.col('weight') / total_weight * n_samples_appx)
```

This will randomly include/exclude rows from your dataset, which is typically comparable to sampling with replacement. You should be careful about interpretation if you have RHS that exceeds 1 -- weighted sampling is a nuanced process that, rigorously speaking, should only be performed with-replacement.

So if you want to sample with replacement instead, you can use F.rand() to get samples of the poisson distribution which will tell you how many copies of the row to include, and you can either treat that value as a weight, or do some annoying joins & unions to duplicate your rows. But I find that this is typically not required.

You can also do this in a portable repeatable way with the hash:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

n_samples_appx = 100
total_weight = df.agg(F.sum('weight')).collect().values
df.filter(F.hash(F.col('id')) % (total_weight / n_samples_appx * F.col('weight')).astype('int') == 0)
```

This will sample at a rate of 1-in-modulo, which incorporates your weight. `hash()` should be a consistent and deterministic function, but the sampling will occur like random.

Comment: Nice approach. I needed to modify it a little to work with PySpark, since the returned Python list from collect does not have a `values` property. I used `total_weight = df.agg(F.sum('weight')).collect()[0][0]`.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is to use `udf` to make a sampling column. This column will have a random number multiplied by your desired weight. Then we sort by the sampling column, and take the top N.

Consider the following illustrative example:

**Create Dummy Data**

```python
import numpy as np
import string
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

index = range(100)
weights = [i%26 for i in index]
labels = [string.ascii_uppercase[w] for w in weights]

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    zip(index, labels, weights),
    ('index', 'label', 'weight')
)

df.show(n=5)
#+-----+-----+------+
#|index|label|weight|
#+-----+-----+------+
#|    0|    A|     0|
#|    1|    B|     1|
#|    2|    C|     2|
#|    3|    D|     3|
#|    4|    E|     4|
#+-----+-----+------+
#only showing top 5 rows
```

**Add Sampling Column**

In this example, we want to sample the DataFrame using the column `weight` as the weight. We define a `udf` using `numpy.random.random()` to generate uniform random numbers and multiply by the weight. Then we use `sort()` on this column and use `limit()` to get the desired number of samples.

```python
N = 10  # the number of samples

def get_sample_value(x):
    return np.random.random() * x

get_sample_value_udf = f.udf(get_sample_value, FloatType())

df_sample = df.withColumn('sampleVal', get_sample_value_udf(f.col('weight')))\
    .sort('sampleVal', ascending=False)\
    .select('index', 'label', 'weight')\
    .limit(N)
```

**Result**

As expected, the DataFrame `df_sample` has 10 rows, and it's contents tend to have letters near the end of the alphabet (higher weights).

```python
df_sample.count()
#10

df_sample.show()
#+-----+-----+------+
#|index|label|weight|
#+-----+-----+------+
#|   23|    X|    23|
#|   73|    V|    21|
#|   46|    U|    20|
#|   25|    Z|    25|
#|   19|    T|    19|
#|   96|    S|    18|
#|   75|    X|    23|
#|   48|    W|    22|
#|   51|    Z|    25|
#|   69|    R|    17|
#+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: This is a clever idea; however, it will not produce a sample that follows the distribution specified by the weights. Consider a DF with two tuples "A" and "B" with weights 1 and 2 respectively. If you do a little math (or simulation) you will notice that tuple A will be sampled with probability 0.25, which is smaller than expected given the distribution of weights.